# Putting words from a file into a hash map (c++)

Tags: c++, dictionary, file-io, while-loop, hashmap

So, I have a text file that is quite long (10k+ words) and I am trying to put each unique word into a hash map using the standard map library.

I have a while loop reading each word from the file. The problem is, this while loop NEVER seems to end. I even put an if statement in the loop so that if it reached the eof() it would break the loop. It still does not end. Here is my code thus far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;


string lowerCase(string isUpper);

void main()
{
//create hash map
map<string, int> stringCounts;

//temp string
string nextString;

//import file/write file
ofstream writeFile;
ifstream gooseFile;

//open file to read from
gooseFile.open("goose.txt");
if (gooseFile.is_open()) {
    //read file word by word
    while (gooseFile >> nextString) { //WORKS DO NOT CHANGE
        //check for punctuation
        for (int i = 0; i < nextString.length(); i++) { //WORKS DO NOT CHANGE
            if (nextString[i] == ',' || nextString[i] == '!' || nextString[i] == ';' || nextString[i] == '-' || nextString[i] == '.' || nextString[i] == '?' || nextString[i] == ':' || nextString[i] == '"' || nextString[i] == '(' || nextString[i] == ')' || nextString[i] == '_' || nextString[i] == '\'') {
                nextString.erase(i, i);
                i--;
            }
        }
        //put all into lowercase
        nextString = lowerCase(nextString); //WORKS DO NOT CHANGE
        //cout << nextString << endl;

        //increment key value
        stringCounts[nextString]++;

        if (gooseFile.eof())
            break;
    }
}

//close current file
gooseFile.close();
cout << "I GOT HERE!";
//now print to an output file
writeFile.open("output.txt");
if (writeFile.is_open()) {
    cout << "ITS OPEN AGAIN";
    //write size of map
    writeFile << "The size of the hash map is " << stringCounts.size() << endl;
    //write all words in map
    //create iterator
    map<string, int>::iterator i = stringCounts.begin();
    //iterate through map 
    while (i != stringCounts.end()) {
        writeFile << "The key and value is : (" << i->first << "," << i->second << ")\n";
        i++;
    }
}
else
    cout << "CANT OPEN\n";
}


string lowerCase(string isUpper)
{
    string toReplace = isUpper;
    for (int i = 0; i < toReplace.length(); i++) {
        if (toReplace[i] >= 65 && toReplace[i] <= 90) {
            toReplace[i] = tolower(toReplace[i]);
        }
    }
    return toReplace;
}
```

Comment: `std::map` is not implemented using hash tables - its usually done with BSTs

Answer (score 3):

```
nextString.erase(i, i);
```

I doubt this is what you want. `string::erase` (the one you are calling) expects a position (for where to start erasing) and a count (for how many characters to erase). So this line erases a number of characters equivalent to the position of the character in the string. So, for example, if `i` is 0, this will erase 0 characters. Combine that fact with the next line:

```
i--;
```

And if the first character is punctuation, `i` will stay at 0 and the for loop will never end. If you want to just erase 1 character, you can do this:

```
nextString.erase(i, 1);
```

But it would be much better to replace that whole for loop and just use the remove/erase idiom.

```
auto new_end = std::remove_if(nextString.begin(), nextString.end(),
        [](char c) {
            // return true if c is punctuation
        });
nextString.erase(new_end, nextString.end());
```